# Differences between an asp.net app vs a wcf app with webHttpBinding

Tags: asp.net, wcf, webhttpbinding

I have a WCF service that makes several TCP endpoints available and I'm looking at allowing a webHttpBinding as well.

So far it seems pretty straightforward to allow requests from a browser to such an enpoint, which returns a `Stream` of HTML text that the browser just displays.

Functionally, what is the difference between serving HTML pages from a WCF service vs from an asp.net service?

I'm still quite new at WCF, but I suspect it would not be very difficult to make a logical API available to a browser client that maps to service methods that build up HTML via/without a templating engine.